# Format number in thousands separators with jq json cli

Tags: json, formatting, integer, jq

Given `{"a": 1234567890}`, I want `1,234,567,890` in the result, how this can be done with jq

```
echo '{"a": 1234567890}' | jq '.a | FORMAT?'
```

Thanks for @peak's answer, the solution is

```
echo '{"a": 1234567890}' | jq -r 'def h: [while(length>0; .[:-3]) | .[-3:]] | reverse | join(","); .a | tostring | h'
//-> 1,234,567,890
```

Comment: How should `1234567` be formatted? `1,234,567` or `1234,567`?

Comment: @Inian 1,234,567

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an idiomatic one-liner definition:

```
def h: tostring | [while(length>0; .[:-3]) | .[-3:]] | reverse | join(",");
```

### Example

```
12, 123, 1234, 12345678 | h
```

#### Output (using -r option):

```
12
123
1,234
12,345,678
```

Answer (score 3):

`jq` doesn't have (yet) a `printf` function to format according locale settings.
If that's an option for you can pass the number to the shell using `printf`:

```
echo '{"a": 12345}' | jq '.a' | xargs printf "%'.f\n"
12,345
```

Note that the printf conversion relies on the format `%'.f` that is explained in `man 3 printf`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a generic solution for integers or integer-valued strings:

```
# "h" for "human-readable"
def h:
  def hh: .[0] as $s | .[1] as $answer
    | if ($s|length) == 0 then $answer
      else ((if $answer == "" then "" else "," end) + $answer ) as $a
      | [$s[0:-3], $s[-3:] + $a] | hh
      end;
   [ tostring, ""] | hh;
```

### Example

```
12, 123, 1234, 12345678 | h
```

### Result (using -r option):

```
12
123
1,234
12,345,678
```